# Getting conversation in stand-alone reply window in Outlook C#

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to GetConversation() while replying to email in stand alone reply window. But it is showing conversation = null. I can get conversation through email in inbox but when I trying to get conversation while replying the same email, it doesn't return anything. My code is below.

```
object selectedItem  = application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
Outlook.MailItem SelectedReply = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
If (SelectedReply is Outlook.MailItem)
{
Outlook.Conversation conv = SelectedReply.GetConversation();
if (conv != null)
  {
    // Code here
  }
  else
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Conversation is not available.");
  }
}
```

I get messagebox "Conversation is not available".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) returns **Null** (**Nothing** in Visual Basic) if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

- The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.
- For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.
- Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.
- The store does not support `Conversation` view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the `IsConversationEnabled` property of the `Store` object to determine whether the store supports `Conversation` view.

So, I'd suggest calling the `Save` method at least before calling the `GetConversation` method:

```
object selectedItem  = application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
Outlook.MailItem SelectedReply = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
If (SelectedReply is Outlook.MailItem)
{
    SelectedReply.Save();
    Outlook.Conversation conv = SelectedReply.GetConversation();
    if (conv != null)
    {
       // Code here
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Conversation is not available.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your code is using ActiveInspector to get at the selected item, but ActiveInspector is for the active full window of an opened email or a reply.  If you want to get a a handle on the reply in the Explorer window (an Inline Response), you need to access it via the Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse property.